# allowsMultipleSelection is not working in Swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, multipleselection

I am more than frustrated as it has wasted lot of my time.
I don't know why allowsMultipleSelection is not working in my TableView?
What all things has to be done to make it work, I did but still no result.
Please take a look on my code and kindly let me know the issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.participantsTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

if tableView == participantsTableView
        {
            var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

            if cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }

            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            }

            self.participantsTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: where do you put the code `if tableView == participantsTableView~`? in function `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`? if so, you don't need to reload table.

Comment: Yes in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and I have tried the same without reloading tableView as well!

Comment: pls post the code in table's datasource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: var cell = UITableViewCell()
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("participantsCell") as UITableViewCell
            
            cell.textLabel.text = "test"
 return cell

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement delegate method `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` and update cell's accessoryType in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)

    if let selectedPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
        let selected = selectedPaths.filter(){ $0 == indexPath }
        if selected.count > 0 {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```